# The wicked redemption: chiddush of the Rabbeinu Gershom

Tags: commentaries, messianic-redemption, zionism, maseches-tamid, rabbeinu-gershom

The Gemara in Tamid 32a writes:

> He said to them: Who among you is wiser than the others? They said to him: We are all equal in wisdom, as every matter that you say to us, we solve for you unanimously. He said to them: What is the substance of this stance, by which you, the Jewish people, oppose me? Since you are my subjects, and my people constitute the majority, you should concede that our lifestyle is superior. **They said to him: Your dominance is inconsequential, as sometimes even the Satan is victorious, by convincing people to act in a manner that is clearly incorrect.** (Sefaria translation, emphasise mine).

The Rabbeinu Gershom, Rabbi Gershom ben Yehudah, explains [in his commentary on this Gemara](https://www.sefaria.org/Rabbeinu_Gershom_on_Tamid.32a.10) that this means that the Satan leads the wicked astray and gives them a redemption.

> אמרו ליה סטנא נצח. כלומר אל תתמה על זה שהשטן הוא נוצח שמתעה אותם ונותן להם גאולה ולסוף יורידם לגיהנם

What exactly does this mean? What is this "redemption" ***and are there sources that say this is somewhat connected to the end of days (Chevlei Moshiach, Ikvesa DiMeshicha)?***

See also the [Zohar in Tetzaveh, with the commentary of the Sulam](https://www.sefaria.org/Zohar,_Tetzaveh.4.42), where it interprets the words "mikeitz yamim" and "mikeitz yamin" (Daniel 12:13) to mean that there will be two kinds of redemptions, one from the evil side, and one redemption from the holy side.

As always, please use sources and I love to have some "pearls" of insights on this :).

Comment: A guess: Gehinom is their redemtion e.g. Derech Hashem 2:4 - https://www.sefaria.org/Derekh_HaShem%252C_Part_Two%252C_On_Mankind_in_This_World.4. This follows well with Yishayahu that the redemption of the nations will come about through their inflicting the Jews with suffering, and eventually waking up to the horror of what they did r'l

Comment: @שלום I don't see the connection.

Comment: Yes, I saw that, but the question was what this "redemption" means?

Comment: It seems like it just means he gives them a break by delaying their punishment and allowing them to remain “free” in this world…

Comment: That I understand. However, that does not fit in with the statement of the Rabbeinu Gershom that "the Satan leads the wicked astray and gives them a redemption".

Comment: @Shmuel, I don’t see how it doesn’t fit in - can you please elaborate?

Comment: Because the Gemara interprets it as " sometimes even the Satan is victorious, by convincing people to act in a manner that is clearly incorrect.". To me, it would seem that the Satan misleads people in thinking that there is redemption, to this, the R' Gershom says that the Satan leads the wicked astray and gives them a redemption. According to this, to me, it does not sound as saying that their punishment is delayed.

Comment: The Satan misleads people because he is allowed to give them respite and salvation (of a sort) after following his advice after which they go to *gehinnom* as punishment for allowing themselves to be misled by the Satan.